# How can I trace an IP address (ipv4 or ipv6) back to my home network?

Tags: networking, nat, ipv6

I am trying to see if my Netflix account has been hacked.  I can see the IP addresses that are streaming from the account. However, I'm not sure how to trace the IP address to see the source.  I'm wondering if there is a way to see what the public facing IP address is for all devices on my home network?  I would expect this would be the only way to do it since the addresses are NAT'd from my home network.  Do routers typically provide this information?

Comment: https://www.whatismyip.com/

Comment: I needed functionality that no other such service appeared to offer at the time, so I built my own: https://myip.addr.space/ I should probably get back to finishing it.

Comment: https://ifconfig.co/ is quite interesting too (script friendly)

Answer (score 3):

Use a website like https://www.whatismyip.com/ or search Google for whatismyip for alternatives.

This has some advantages:

- You don't have to login to your router.
- You get your public facing IP even if the provider uses NAT.
- You can also use it in a hotel or other public network where you don't have access to the router.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if there is a way to see what the public facing IP address is for all devices on my home network? I would expect this would be the only way to do it since the addresses are NAT'd from my home network. Do routers typically provide this information?

Yes – usually it's just a matter of logging in to the router's configuration page and looking. (In some models the IP addresses are shown directly in the front page "summary"; the rest will have an interface configuration section of some sort.) After all, the router needs this information to *work,* so there's no reason it wouldn't show it.

[image]
[image]
[image]

(That said, this is assuming that the only NAT is done by *your own* router. But if you're unlucky enough that the ISP has put you behind carrier-grade NAT and doesn't give you a "public" IP address to begin with, then of course you won't see it in your router's configuration...)

The alternate method is to ask an Internet service about what address they *see* as yours. There are many websites dedicated to it; indeed if you google [what is my ip](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+ip) you'll get an automatic result with your address as seen by Google at that moment. (Note that this doesn't tell you whether the address is dedicated to you, or shared among several customers in the case of CGNAT, so both methods should be combined.)

Answer (score -1):

The same thing happened with me a year back, I was totally confused about what to do. I reset my Netflix password twice. Later on, I have used [Whatizmyip](https://whatizmyip.xyz) . I got to know that person's location by latitude and longitude.